# Ektron search service not indexing with SOLR

Tags: solr, ektron

With Ektron 9.1, we have what we think is a complete install of Ektron with ektron SOLR Search setup and Manifold running etc.

The Settings -> Search -> Node status returns everything as running OK.

But there are no documents in the SOLR interface for the node in question, no documents are in the index at all.

Any ideas on where to start debugging this?
I've turned up the log level where applicable but it's not showing anything wrong.

I've also tried editing some content and clicking Publish, and then requesting a full crawl again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us, it ended up being that the Manifold service in between was the service that was the issue. It's logging isn't verbose enough (even when turned up).  It turned out it couldn't access the database but wasn't explicit about which connection exactly.